# Why reason my Keras cnn model not increase accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying train a CNN Model based on VGG16 with Keras, and i can't get an accuracy greater than 40%~50%. I've augmentated the data, using dropout layers, l2 regularization, weight initializer and many parameters to find best results, but nothing happens.

I tried run my model on Google Colab, it's not a huge Dataset, just 3 folders from PASCAL VOC 2012 challenge, you can see my code above:

```py
#imports ...

#Path to train dir ...

#Model
init = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0, maxval=0.001)
input_shape = (224,224,3)
img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block1_conv2')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

# Block 2
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block2_conv1')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block2_conv2')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

# Block 3
x = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block3_conv1')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block3_conv2')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block3_conv3')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

# Block 4
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block4_conv1')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block4_conv2')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block4_conv3')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

# Block 5
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block5_conv1')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block5_conv2')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(10, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer=init,
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001),
                  name='block5_conv3')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

x = layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001), kernel_initializer=init)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001), kernel_initializer=init)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

model = Model(img_input, x, name='overfeat_vgg16')
#model.summary()

#creating generators
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, zoom_range=0.4, horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, classes=["bird","cat","dog"], shuffle=True, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=64, class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, classes=["bird","cat","dog"], shuffle=True, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=64, class_mode='categorical')

#compiling model
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=True)
#adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#training
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=5850 // 64,
        epochs=100,
        shuffle = True,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=5850 // 64)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

There are the current results:

Epoch 1/100
91/91 [==============================] - 172s 2s/step - loss: 1.0449 - acc: 0.4301 - val_loss: 1.0432 - val_acc: 0.4239

Epoch 2/100
91/91 [==============================] - 155s 2s/step - loss: 1.0421 - acc: 0.4188 - val_loss: 1.0411 - val_acc: 0.3984

Epoch 3/100
91/91 [==============================] - 155s 2s/step - loss: 1.0388 - acc: 0.4263 - val_loss: 1.0382 - val_acc: 0.4250

... and for all epochs the results keep the same.

I just don't know what i need to do for better results.

Comment: "it's not a huge Dataset" Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to answer without actually knowing your dataset I fear. It is very much possible that your data is incapable of reaching a better result no matter how you process it.

Comment: I figured the dataset would be the problem. Each class has about 500 images for training and about 100 for validation. I still extracted parts of the image to try to generate extra data but it didn't work. The way is to keep trying to generate more data or use another dataset.

Comment: @CristianoSiebert 500 images isn't a lot of data for a CNN...

Comment: When I'm unclear whether it's my dataset or my model implementation, I find it helpful to load a similar pretrained model. For example, run your dataset through Keras Applications' VGG16. If your results are very similar, it points to dataset. Otherwise, perhaps architecture. After all, simply adding more features like regularizers doesn't equally simply improve the network.